# Change to later version of Vaadin in a NetBeans project using Vaadin plugin

Tags: netbeans, version, vaadin, vaadin7, netbeans-8

I am using the [*Vaadin Plug-in for Netbeans*](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans) version 1.1.0 with NetBeans 8.1 & 8.2 (as [shown here](https://vaadin.com/framework/get-started#netbeans). This plugin defaults to using Vaadin 7.5.9 rather than the current version of Vaadin for a new project created by choosing `File` > `New Project` > `Categories` (list) > `Vaadin` > `Projects` (list) > `Vaadin Multi Module Project`.

How does one change the Vaadin version from 7.5.9 to 7.7.3 (the latest)?

By context-clicking on the “…-ui” module in the `Projects` navigator in NetBeans, I accessed the `Properties` > `Project Properties` > `Categories` (list) > `Vaadin` (list item) > `Vaadin Version` pop-up menu.

[image]

This seemed to work. But when I do a clean-and-build on the `…-parent` module, I still see line items for Vaadin version 7.5.9 in the NetBeans console output.

So what is the proper way to get a Vaadin multi-module project in NetBeans 8 to use a later version of Vaadin?

Comment: Since these are pom.xml files, just change the vaadin version in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Something is broken with latest Vaadin version support for projects.

Version 7.5.9 used to be the latest available version when the NetBeans plugin has been built. To be able to support latest stable versions plugin reads some URL from vaadin.com site and uses versions from there.

But apparently this is broken. New projects are created with old version.
Could you please create a ticket for that here https://github.com/vaadin/netbeans-plugin/issues ? Thanks a lot.

We are working currently on Vaadin version 8.0 and soon we will have to release new NetBeans plugin version to support it. So this issue might be fixed in this update.

Multimodule project support is not completely implemented unfortunately. That's why version is not correctly updated via project settings.
You can create an issue about this as well (though I think I already made it in our old tracker https://dev.vaadin.com/).

But back to your issue: you can fix it via editing POM file manually.
Please open POM.xml file in your root parent project and find

```
<properties>
```

section.

There is `<vaadin.version>7.5.9</vaadin.version>` string. Just replace `7.5.9` with required version.

Thanks and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, info, and suggesting to file bug report. I had reported to the old TRAC but have now filed on GitHub: [Defaults to Vaadin 7.5.9 rather than current 7.7.x for new project](https://github.com/vaadin/netbeans-plugin/issues/4) and [Multi-module support does not complete the Vaadin version update change](https://github.com/vaadin/netbeans-plugin/issues/5).

Comment: Thanks a lot Basil.